# Code wars : Title Case with python

Tags: python, indexing

```
def title_case(title, minor_words = 0):
    title = title.lower().split(" ")
    title_change = []
    temp = []
    if minor_words != 0 :
        minor_words = minor_words.lower().split(" ")
        for i in range(len(title)):
            if (i != 0 and title[i] not in minor_words) or (i == 0 and title[i] in minor_words):
                temp = list(title[i].lower())
                temp[0] = temp[0].upper()
                title_change.append("".join(temp))
            else:
                title_change.append(title[i])
            temp = []
    else:
        for i in range(len(title)):
            temp = list(title[i])
            temp[0] = temp[0].upper()
            title_change.append("".join(temp))
            temp = []
    return " ".join(title_change)
```

Hello,this is my python code here.
This is the question:
A string is considered to be in title case if each word in the string is either (a) capitalised (that is, only the first letter of the word is in upper case) or (b) considered to be an exception and put entirely into lower case unless it is the first word, which is always capitalised.

Write a function that will convert a string into title case, given an optional list of exceptions (minor words). The list of minor words will be given as a string with each word separated by a space. Your function should ignore the case of the minor words string -- it should behave in the same way even if the case of the minor word string is changed.

I am trying not to use capitalize() to do this.It seems my code works fine on my computer,but the code wars just prompted "IndexError: list index out of range".

Comment: what is code wars?

Comment: Codewars.kind of a coding practicing website.

Comment: Does it give the line number the `IndexError` occurs on?

Comment: It didn't.I just print out the index,it also shows fine.

Comment: does it work on your computer if the input title is: `""` an empty string?

Comment: if you use `minor_words = ""` as your default value, you won't need the if `if minor_words != 0` or the `else`. It looks like a lot of code is duplicated between the two cases; maybe simplifying it down a little will help isolate the error?

Comment: You should get the full traceback from the error, including the line number.

Comment: I just ran it, no `IndexError`.

Comment: Try it with a string with a trailing space, for example: `"hello "`

Comment: `title_case("foo bar baz ")` raises `IndexError` but `title_case("foo bar baz ", "")` or `title_case("foo bar baz ", " ")` do not.

Comment: From a Python style viewpoint, I would make the default `minor_words=None`. Also, bad form (i.e. potentially dangerous) to mutate arguments passed in to your function.

Comment: Indeed, make sure your dataset is complete, for instance, try the empty string "" and you should get that error

Comment: Thanks for help here.The editor on the website don't show which line had problem which confused a lot.I just rewrote it with capitalize() method,and it somehow passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will break if `title` has leading or trailing spaces, or two consecutive spaces, such as `"foo  bar"`. It will also break on an empty string. That's because `title.lower().split(" ")` on any of those kinds of titles will give you an empty string as one of your "words", and then `temp[0]` will cause an `IndexError` later on.

You can avoid the issue by using `split()` with no argument. It will split on any kind of whitespace in any combinations. Multiple spaces will be treated just like one space, and leading or trailing whitespace will be ignored. An empty string will become an empty list when `split` is called, rather than a list with one empty string in it.

Comment: -deleted mine, your answer is better 0_o.... it'll also break if `title = ""` however

Comment: @Aaron: I'd omitted the case of an empty string, which you mentioned in your answer. Since that's probably the most likely input that causes problems for the OP's code, I've edited my answer to include it as well as the others.

Comment: Really thanks for the help here.I think its editor may has some problems.I will just make you the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a supplement to @Blckknght's explanation, here is an illuminating console session that steps through what's happening to your variable.

```
>>> title = ''
>>> title = title.lower().split(' ')
>>> title
['']
>>> temp = list(title[0])
>>> temp
[]
>>> temp[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried your solution on other (non-whitespace) inputs, and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for helps here.

Comment: Then I quickly found this line in my code  (i == 0 and title[i] in minor_words) it seems its just need i==0 and the other is redundant.